# I want my wp 2.8.6 blog to be seen as written in Spanish by Feedburner

Tags: wordpress

As best I can see, when the blog `.xml` includes the following line:
http://feeds.feedburner.com/~d/styles/rss2spanishfull.xsl

then **FeedBurner** automatically interprets it as **Spanish** and when a potential subscriber makes a request.

I do not know how to get that line into my WordPress `.xml` feed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This isn't a programming question and doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more information? Is your WP Blog current written in Spanish? I'm confused, I think what you are trying to say is you want your Feedburner feed to also be in Spanish. This is most likely a Feedburner setting.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Mind marking my answer correct, I'm trying to get rep points (by earning then not by begging for them) 

Thanks,
Brooke

Answer (score 0):

Hi Brandon: You were right - it can be fixed via feedburner under the optimization section.
I had thought that it had to be part of the WP XML creation (actually it probably could be) - but anyway Feedburner can do this.... many thanks.

The Blog is in Spanish - but the Feedburner automatically uses English settings. So when subscribers click for their RSS feed the default page is in English.